# '\includepdf' misincludes PDF as figure

Tags: pdfpages

I used `\inclduepdf` to include a document with 
`\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{docs/content.pdf}`.

In `docs/content.pdf`, I have pictures and texts in it. And you can highlight words with cursor. In the new file, some pages are included successfully. The text can be highlighted. While in other pages, the page acts like a picture: (1) when zoom in, the text become pixels (2) you cannot highlight the text.

Did I miss some options that might automatically transform a page into a figure?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also: Are you using pdflatex, lualatex or xelatex? Which pdf version do the embedded pdfs have? Are there any restrictions on the pdfs you are trying to include?

Comment: @DG' thanks for your reply. The included pdf is compiled with PDFTeXify and the main pdf is compiled with Xelatex. Because the pdf is a submitted paper, it should not be disclosed. I will try to reproduce it with minimal code.

Comment: BTW, the abnormally included pages are pages with picture in the beginning.